# Replacing a word in a psycopg2.sql.Composed object

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a rather complex [`psycopg2.sql.Composed`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Composed) object on which I simply need to replace a word for retro-compatibility issue.

Before having such an object, I was having an f-string on which this snippet worked like a charm:

```
if v4:
    sql_update_query = re.sub(
        'word_to_replace,',
        'new_replacement_word',
         sql_update_query
    )
```

I naively tried to do on the `psycopg2.sql.Composed` object:

```
if v4:
    sql_update_query = re.sub(
        'word_to_replace,',
        'new_replacement_word',
         sql_update_query.as_string(conn) # conversion to a string for re.sub() to work
    )
```

It's OK, but then how to get back to a true `psycopg2.sql.Composed` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I noticed that the replacement was done on column identifiers only.

Therefore, I extracted them out in a list and did the replacement within the list itself, e.g. as :

```
columns_list = [
    re.sub(
        '^word_to_replace$',
        'new_replacement_word',
        col
    ) for col in columns
]
```

Please, notice that I had a comma at the end of the word to replace in the original post; it was a trick because some columns were starting with the same name but then with some `_suffixes`. Therefore, I had to precise at least using the dollar sign in the `re.sub()` first expression, that I restrict the word to be replace to this particular one, letting all suffixes versions untouched.

Then I added the columns as `sql.Identifier`:

```
sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, columns_list)),
```

and voila.